# How to read data from two Serial Port devices from Android device?

Tags: android, serial-port, usbserial

I am using https://github.com/felHR85/SerialPortExample to read data from one serial device using OTG cable and Serial to USB converter (prolific pl2303 chipset).

I am successfully able to get data from one device but when I connected the 2nd Device using a USB hub, I am always getting the data of the first device connected.

The project blog page is:https://felhr85.net/2015/01/09/a-dirty-and-quick-example-of-serial-port-communication-in-android/

Any help is highly appreciated which will point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement but found out that it's not possible without using a 3rd controller which will connect to those two devices to the mobile application.